# How to switch tab in same page using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<tabset class="overflowhidden marginbottom0" tabset-name="clientTabset">

<tab heading="General" title="general">
<p>Hello</p>
<button  ng-click="general()"  class="btn btn-primary"  has-permission='CREATE_CLIENT'>Next</button>
</tab>

<tab heading="Address" title="address" >
<p>hello world </p>
</tab>

</tabset>
```

I want to switch tab from general to address tab after clicking Next Button

Comment: make use of `ng-show` or `ng-hide`.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can try using active true

**js**

```
$scope.active = {
    one: false,
    two: true
  };
```

**HTMl**

```
 <tabset>
    <tab heading="General" title="general">
        One
         <button  ng-click="general()"  class="btn btn-primary"  has-permission='CREATE_CLIENT'>Next</button>
      </tab>
      <tab heading="Address" title="address"  active="active.two">Two</tab>
    </tabset>
```

for reference https://plnkr.co/edit/nRHFHDByvcQhiQTDkbFh?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

javascript

```
$scope.general = function () {
  $scope.active = 1;
}
```

html

```
<tabset class="overflowhidden marginbottom0" tabset-name="clientTabset" active="active">

  <tab heading="General" title="general" index="0">
    <p>Hello</p>
    <button ng-click="general()" class="btn btn-primary" has-permission='CREATE_CLIENT'>Next</button>
  </tab>

  <tab heading="Address" title="address" index="1">
    <p>hello world</p>
  </tab>

</tabset>
```

reference: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/tabs